# Apollo GraphQL iOS - Getting 'No operations found to generate` error when trying to use `ID` in query

Tags: ios, apollo

I am working on an iOS application to communicate with our GraphQL backend using Apollo's GraphQL library. With the query below, I am able to generate swift code that I can use to query backend.

```
query mobileApp {
  app(id: "content/mobileApp) {
    title
  } 
}
```

I am using the following commands to generate Swift code

`../../Pods/Apollo/scripts/apollo/bin/run client:codegen --target=swift --includes ../app.graphql --localSchemaFile=./downloaded_schema.json API.swift`

However, if I replace the string literal passed into the app(...) with ID like this

```
query mobileApp {
  app(id: ID!) {
    title
  } 
}
```

running same codegen command fails with following error.

```
Generating query files with 'swift' target
    → No operations or fragments found to generate code for.
Error: No operations or fragments found to generate code for.
    at write (~/Downloads/ios-app/Pods/Apollo/scripts/apollo/lib/commands/client/codegen.js:65:39)
    at Task.task (~/Downloads/ios-app/Pods/Apollo/scripts/apollo/lib/commands/client/codegen.js:90:46)
```

I have no clue what's wrong with the query above. Hoping that someone can point me in right direction, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the error by updating my query as below based on comment here

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/issues/1320#issuecomment-660693070

```
query mobileApp($id: ID!) { 
  app(id: $id) {
    title
  }
}
```